# Need to display empty if select option is "" want to use a javascript ternary

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I have several select dropdowns in which if they are not "" then I want to use up displaying the value along with adding a \n  for a new line

```
crewMembers += $('#aa').find(":selected").text();
crewMembers += $('#bb').find(":selected").text();
crewMembers += $('#cc').find(":selected").text();
crewMembers += $('#dd').find(":selected").text();
crewMembers += $('#ee').find(":selected").text();
crewMembers += $('#ff').find(":selected").text();
```

So with that code what I want to do is

use a ternary

```
aa ? aa + "\n" : "";
```

this type of code in testing it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't know why you need a ternary, and I don't know where do you are trying to write it to doesn't works

Comment: Do you use the variable `crewMembers` in your ternary operator?

Comment: I suppose he need to use it somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

A [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ouh0ssqq/3/) showing how to implement this, so instead of writing a separated line for each `select` input, we add same `class` to all of them thus we can simplify the work with `.each()` function. we loop through every element of these group and check its value, if `0` we return `""` otherwise we return the selected option text using javascript ternary.

```js
var crewMembers = '', val, data;
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.slct').each(function(){
        val = $(this).val();
        data = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        crewMembers += (val != 0) ? data + "\n" : "";    
    });
    console.log(crewMembers);
    
    //below is just a demonstration as well as the console - 
    //not part of the solution
    var html = $('#result').html() + crewMembers.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
    $('#result').html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="aa" class="slct">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">option 1.1</option>
    <option value="2">option 1.2</option>
    <option value="3">option 1.3</option>
    <option value="4">option 1.4</option>
</select>
<select id="bb" class="slct">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">option 2.1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2.2</option>
</select>
<select id="aa" class="slct">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">option 3.1</option>
    <option value="2">option 3.2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3.3</option>
</select>
<select id="dd" class="slct">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">option 4.1</option>
    <option value="2">option 4.2</option>
    <option value="3">option 4.3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4.4</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">check</button>
<hr>
    <div id="result"><strong>Result:</strong><br></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the need of the ternary operatior, you can use this:

```
crewMembers += $('#aa').find(":selected").text() ?
    $('#aa').find(":selected").text() + '\n' :
    '';
```

But i do not recommend that. Instead I recommend something like this:

```
crewMembers = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'].map(function (a) {
    return $('#' + a).find(":selected").text();
}).filter(Boolean).join('\n');
```

This proposal features an array and it's methods.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP need to do it using ternary and that is his problem.

Comment: He is asking about the method of validation. You are providing an alternative way of collecting data. That is fundamentally wrong. Use comments if you have a remark about his question. Use answers if you can address his issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using length.

```
aa.length > 0 ? aa + "\n" : "";
```